# Algorithm to create an optimal "summary" of a list of permutations (or tuples)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, permutation, combinatorics

Searched is an algorithm, to create an "optimal summary" of a list of permutations (or tuples).

Example, you have the tuples:

1-2-3
1-2-4

the summary would be:

1-2-3/4

the optimal summary would be, for any set of tuples, the minimum number of summarized lines.

Example, for the input:

4-2-3
1-2-3
4-5-6
4-5-3

the "optimal summary" would be:

1/4-2-3
4-5-3/6

a suboptimal solution would be:

1-2-3
4-2/5-3
4-5-6

1/4-2/5-3/6 would not be a solution, because that would contain the tuple 1-2-6, which isn't in the input set

The order of the input/output is not important:

1-2-3
1-2-4

is the same input as

1-2-4
1-2-3

but of course in the tuples, the order is important:

1-2-3

is not the same as

3-2-1

the algorithm should run in under 1 second for an input set of ~200 3-tuples, on a typical machine.

Assumption: there will be no duplicate tuples in the input set

the input:

1-2-3
1-2-3

is invalid

Comment: OK, and the question?...

Comment: And, can't the optimal summary in 2nd example be: `1/4, 2/5, 3/6`? If not, why?

Comment: that would include the tuple 1-2-6, but that was not in the input set!

Comment: the question of course is to provide an algorithm which computes the optimal solution (and brute force is not feasible in this case)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to the [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), and is therefore NP-Complete.

Comment: Is order significant?  Can an input tuple be summarised more than once?

Comment: edited to clarify some more

Comment: Can an input tuple be summarised more than once?

Comment: that is allowed yes. but the union of all summaries must be equal to the input set. no more and no less.

Comment: why not build a dfa and convert it to a regular expression? for your first example, the RE will be (1|4-2-3)|(4-5-3|6)